# Unexplainable Typescript compiler error on Visual Studio Code on a Mac

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I can't get my project to build anymore due to a Typescript error in Visual Studio Code.

I'm pair programming with a colleague; I like to use Yarn, they like to use NPM (and yes, I know mixing and matching package managers is bad). I recently downloaded their branch to my local machine and hit a series of errors. Unfortunately, I've run out of ideas on how to resolve. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error #1:

```
Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised to not mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json
```

I deleted package-lock.json.

Error #2:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1147:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I deleted all node-module folders through the project and cleared the VS cache using these commands:

```
Clear Editor History
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedData/*
```

I reinstalled all the libraries and then tried to rebuild

```
yarn install
yarn upgrade
yarn build
```

Still, I'm getting this compilation error (but I didn't touch any file related to this component):

```
/Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/src/components/reviews/ReviewPage/ReviewPage.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/me/Desktop/DevSep09/frontend/react/src/components/reviews/ReviewPage/ReviewPage.tsx(25,38):
Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571
```

I also updated Node to the latest version, still no dice.

Comment: I know this probably isn't too helpful, but you already know you're trying to make yarn do something that yarn itself tells you not to do. Do you get the same problems if you use npm?

Comment: Type errors not experienced by another developer working on the same project are usually due to different versions of npm packages being resolved (either by yarn or npm). This makes the types not line up between the packages and errors appear. If a newer version of Typescript has been resolved then extra rules could also be being applied that were not originally adhered to. Usually the  package lock or yarn equivalent would take care of this, but I assume due to the mismatch in package managers this was ignored.

Comment: No, my buddy is using NPM and there are no compilation errors so it's most likely some mismatching dependency but still haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

> I like to use Yarn, they like to use NPM

The best solution would be to move to either and then you will both get the same error.

## Alternative

- You will first have it working with either NPM or YARN. I'll assume you get it working with npm.
- You would then store the lockfile in another folder
- Now run with YARN to get the lockfile.
- Now painfully compare the yarn and the npm lockfiles to see what the different transient dependency is that is causing the issue
- Now add that transient dependency as a hard dependency in your `package.json` so that both YARN and NPM install the correct version.